# Is it safe to call params at slim template in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I just want to know if it is safe to call params like `params[:id]` which come from the request parameter in url `(eg. /?id=<script>console.log(1)</script>)` at slim tempalate for rails like `h3 = params[:id]` because of security reason.

Is the params automatically escaped or sanitized?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on context, but in general I would say rendering raw params directly in a view is an anti-pattern. Params are really the concern of the controller. I can't think of a case where you'd want to render a raw parameter in a view without some preliminary processing, validation, or sanitization.

Params (along with any other value) would be HTML sanitized in the view, although, remember, it's likely that users could provide any value they want here, so it's worth asking yourself what vulnerabilities or boundary conditions this may cause.

Finally, while this isn't an absolute rule, I'm strongly of the opinion that primary IDs should remain a concern of the database. In some cases it may be risky to expose them to the user or outside world. The reason is that you're leaking information about your database (e.g. how many records there are) if the primary key is auto-incrementing, which it usually is. In such cases it might be worth obscuring or hashing the primary key.